# file name from stdin for NSFileManager objective-c

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

I'm trying to teach myself (painfully) how to do file I/O in objective-c.  The following code is intended to let the user enter a file name from stdin and then create a NSFileManager using that name.  The code works if I hard-code the file name as an NSString (shown in the commented code @"barney.txt".  However, nothing appears to happen if I use the same file name with stdin.  The program will NSLog out the name of the file.  But, no dice on the FileManager.

I need help.

Thanks,
Mark Allyn

```
enter code here

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

//NSString * fName = @"barney.txt";
NSFileManager * fm;
//NSDictionary *attr;

NSFileHandle *input = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
NSLog(@"Created file handle...");
NSLog(@"Enter File Name");
NSData *inputData = [input availableData];
NSLog(@"Created NSData object");
NSString *fName = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:inputData              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Created NSString object");
 NSLog(@"You entered %@ as the name\n", fName);
fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init ];  //defaultManager

if (fm == nil)
 {
NSLog(@"Failed to create file manager object\n");

          }
if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:fName] == YES){
NSLog(@"File Exists!");
NSLog(@"%p", fm);
} else 
   {
 NSLog(@"File Appears not to exist");

}
[fm release];
[pool drain];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? Which logs do you see?

Comment: BTW - if you are playing with command line level code and dealing with `stdin`, why are you using iOS and not doing this on the Mac as an OS X app?

Comment: The actual problem is that the program prints "File appears not to exist".

Comment: If I had a Mac I would.  But, I'm running on a linux box (Ubuntu 12.04).  I'm compiling with GNUstep.

Comment: Then the file doesn't exist - at least relative to the app's current working directory.

Comment: Then why is this tagged iOS? You can't be building an iOS app.

Comment: If it doesn't exist, then why is it that if I hard code the file name in as NSString * fName = @"barney.txt" the program runs as expected.  The working directory should be the same, shouldn't it?

Comment: My apologies for mistakenly including the iOS tag.

Comment: What do you log for `fName` when using `stdin`? Make sure there is no newline or other whitespace in the name.

Comment: If I understand your log question, the answer is that NSLog(@"fName"); will print out to stdout the file name I entered on stdin.

Comment: I'm asking what it actually logs. What is the exact output from your `NSLog` statement?

Comment: 2015-05-18 17:25:03.678 FileCheck[12885] File Appears not to exist

Comment: Sorry, wrong NSLog.  The correct NSLog was:  2015-05-18 17:25:03.678 FileCheck[12885] You entered barney
 as the name

Comment: "barney" and "barney.txt" are not the same thing. Did you try to enter "barney.txt"?

Comment: Sorry for the red herring!  You're right, but there are two files, barney.txt and barney.  When I ran the program last time I typed in just barney on the keyboard.  Hence, the output I showed.  However, if I do the same thing with barney.txt on the keyboard it will LOG out the same message.  So, here it is, this time with barney.txt.                                                2015-05-18 17:44:13.551 FileCheck[12948] You entered barney.txt
 as the name

Comment: I added a single line of code to the above program which prints out the heap location of the NSFileManager instance.  The code is NSLog(@"fm maps to %@", fm) .  When I do that right after the attempt to instantiate fm, the resulting output appears to indicate that I actually have created the desired NSFileManager.  The output reads:  2015-05-18 18:13:44.183 FileCheck[13162] fm maps to <NSFileManager: 0x88040a4>.  So, the program is failing at the line: if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:fName] == YES)... or so it appears.

Comment: The answer to my question is simply that using stdin to name the file puts a newline at the end.  This messes up the search for the file.  If you delete the newline the code will run as intended.

Comment: I mentioned that in my 5th comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Using stdin puts a '\n' at the end of the string.  This messes up the search.  If you delete the newline chars the code will run as expected.